# Connecting Java Application (Web and Desktop application using spring) with mongodb

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mongodb

i want to use mongodb as back-end for java based application (web/Desktop). I am using Spring framework.
Could anyone please tell me whether it is possible to connect to mongodb through springDao and is this the best approach? (i need this for both web and desktop application)

Since mongodb is not a relational database, is it possible or recommended to use hibernate ORM in order to connect to mongodb.

Please advise the best approach for the scenarios.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is possible to use mongodb with your java application. Whether it is preferred over other relational databases purely depends on the KIND of application you are developing.

Comment: I suggest reading this. [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/when-use-mongodb-rather-mysql)

Comment: is it possible to use hibernate framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look inside Spring projects tutorials:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

I believe it will help.